# Json String does not shows up after calling second time

Tags: javascript, html, json

**hey im a beginner in js , im facing a problem right now help me if you can** 
Here is my html

```
 <div class="container">
    <button id="button1">Get Costumer</button>
    <button id="button2">Get Costumers</button>
    <br><br>
    <h1>Customer</h1>
    <div id="Customer"></div>
    <h1>Customers</h1>
    <div id="Customers"></div>
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

and js

```
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(xhr);
    xhr.open("GET", "customer.json", !0);
    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', loadCustomer);
    console.log(xhr);

    function loadCustomer() {
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log(1);
            if (this.status === 200) {
                const customer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(customer)
            }
        };
        xhr.send()
    }
```

when i click on the button it just displays one time and throws this error in console

> app.js:33 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
>       at HTMLButtonElement.loadCustomer

where did i go wrong?
[take a look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ8LN.png)

Comment: move  xhr.open("GET", "customer.json", !0); in your loadCustomer()

Comment: it worked thanks a lot bro ! @ManojYadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialize the `xhr` inside the `loadCustomer` method. Just move the initialization code within that method, and it should start working.

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', loadCustomer);

function loadCustomer() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log(xhr);
  xhr.open("GET", "customer.json", !0);
  console.log(xhr);

  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(1);
    if (this.status === 200) {
      const customer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(customer)
    }
  };
  xhr.send()
}
```

---

A couple of unrelated suggestions:

1. Use `true` explicitly, rather than `!0` to improve readability.
2. You should listen to `xhr.onerror` as well. Otherwise you might be left wondering when the request fails.

Comment: that `!0` is done due to pasting my code in some online minifier sir and thanks for your valuable time and teaching me .